# How to get the details of input text and send it to bacend in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table 'component' looks something like this:

```
var dataW = [
  {
    id:1,
    taskName: 'WWWx',
    standarDescription: 'WWW',
    emp_comment: 'WW',
    empRating: '1',
    review_comment: '',
    review_rating:'',
  }

]

var Tablefortask = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: dataW};

  },
  onChange: function (index,event) {
    console.log(event)
    let temp = Object.assign([], this.state.data);
    temp[index].review_rating = event.target.value;
    this.setState({data: temp});
    console.log(index);

  },
  onChangeTextArea : function(index,event){
    let temp = Object.assign([], this.state.data);
    temp[index].review_comment = event.target.value
    this.setState({data: temp})
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="border-basic-task col-md-12">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <table className="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped-col " id="table-data">
            <thead>
              <tr align="center">
                <th>Task  Name</th>
                <th >Standard Discription of Task</th>
                <th>Employee Comment</th>
                <th >Employee Rating</th>
                <th width="30%">Reviewer Comment</th>
                <th >Reviewer Rating</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <TablefortaskList data={this.state.data} onChange={this.onChange} onChangeTextArea={this.onChangeTextArea} />
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TablefortaskList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment,index) {
      return (
        <Addcontenttotable index={index} onChange= {this.props.onChange} onChangeTextArea={this.props.onChangeTextArea}  taskid={comment.id} taskName={comment.taskName} standarDescription={comment.standarDescription} emplComment={comment.emp_comment} empRating={comment.empRating} key={comment.id} reviewComment={comment.review_comment} reviewRating={comment.review_rating} >
        </Addcontenttotable>
      );
    },this);
    return (
      <tbody>{commentNodes}</tbody>
    );
  }
});


var Addcontenttotable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var textAreaClass = this.props.reviewComment === "" &&  this.props.reviewRating !== "" ? "highlight" : "";
    var comboClass = this.props.reviewComment !== "" &&  this.props.reviewRating === "" ? "highlight" : "";
    return (
      <tr><td>{this.props.taskName}</td>
      <td>{this.props.standarDescription}</td>
      <td>{this.props.emplComment}</td>
      <td width="5%">{this.props.empRating}</td>
      <td ><textarea 
        className={textAreaClass} 
        onChange={(e) => this.props.onChangeTextArea(this.props.index,e)}
        name="empComment"
        placeholder="Employee Comment"
        />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select  
        className={comboClass} 
        onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(this.props.index,e)}
        data-placeholder="Basic Select2 Box" >
        <option value="">Option</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

);
}
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Tablefortask />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Now I want to save the data from the Textarea and drop down in datatbase if both are filled for the current row .

I tried doing this way:

```
saveReviewerRating:function(index){
  if(this.props.reviewComment !== "" &&  this.props.reviewRating !== ""){
    console.log('saving');
    console.log(index);
  }
},
render: function() {
  var textAreaClass = this.props.reviewComment === "" &&  this.props.reviewRating !== "" ? "highlight" : "";
  var comboClass = this.props.reviewComment !== "" &&  this.props.reviewRating === "" ? "highlight" : "";
  this.saveReviewerRating(this.props.index);
 }
}
```

But the function `saveReviewerRating` is firing every time I make changes to the other rows , If there are multiple rows , I know this is happening because I have called it inside the rendered function ,

So my question is where Can I implement it?

Comment: Pass your call as a callback to both `setState`s, like this: `setState({ data: temp }, this.saveReviewerRating)`. This way `saveReviewerRating` is called after either state update. You will need to add check to see if both are filled..

Comment: @wintvelt so this way the parent will be able to access the child's function ??

Comment: You should put the function inside parent. A parent can only pass props to child, a parent should never directly call child method. Added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do inside the component tree is save to the database everytime a comment or review *changes*.
What you should not do is save to the database based on props only. If you only need the props to determine whether or not to save, then this function does not belong in the component, but at the place where the props are calculated.

Here's what I think your code is intended to do:

- `<TablefortaskList>` component has the entire table, including review and comment per row, and puts it in state.
- For every row, the `<TablefortaskList>` renders a (stateless) `<Addcontenttotable>` component.
- This `<Addcontenttotable>` has two input fields, that the user can edit
- If either input fields is edited, the `<Addcontenttotable>` calls a function on the parent, to update state.
- On every change event, the parent should check if - for that row - both fields are filled. If so, an external `saveReviewerRating()` function should be called, to update both fields for that row in the database.

For that, you need to make the following changes:

Put the `saveReviewerRating` inside the parent, and make it evaluate specific row:

```
saveReviewerRating:function(index){
  if(this.state.data[index].reviewComment !== "" 
     &&  this.state.data[index].reviewRating !== "")
  {
    console.log('saving');
    console.log(index);
  }
},
```

Change the `setState()` inside both change functions, to include callback, like this:

```
this.setState(
  {data: temp}, 
  () => {this.saveReviewerRating(index)}  // double arrow to pass index to function
)
```

Then it should work.

Comment: something similar I implemented but I am going to check your code, One major problem I am facing is with the , TextAreat because there as soon as I enter one character it is calling the `saveReviewerRating` function and becoz of this in the databse a row is being created now if I try to add another character the The Server add another row which is wrong

Comment: I see: that is a different question. 1) your database code should be able to UPDATE a record instead of always adding another record and 2) you could modify the event in the textarea rendering from `onChange=` to `onBlur=`. That way, the event only fires when user leaves the textarea field.